# How to remove not null constraint in sql server using query

Tags: sql-server, sql

I am trying to remove not null constraint in sql server 2008 without losing data.

Answer (score 262, accepted):

```
 ALTER TABLE YourTable ALTER COLUMN YourColumn columnType NULL
```

Comment: I found I had to include the type in YourColumn eg. ALTER TABLE YourTable ALTER COLUMN YourColumn int NULL

Comment: or you can do : alter table table_name modify column_name type(30) NULL. 30 being the size of your column type, example: varchar(30)

Comment: In postgres: `ALTER TABLE YourTable ALTER COLUMN YourColumn DROP NOT NULL`

Answer (score 3):

Remove constraint `not null` to `null`

```
ALTER TABLE 'test' CHANGE COLUMN 'testColumn' 'testColumn' datatype NULL;
```

Comment: Why does this work and not the above accepted answer for mysql ?

Comment: @HopeKing the question was about Microsoft SQL Server and not MySql.

Comment: I'm finding that our copy of MS SQL Server 2019 isn't familiar with the `change` keyword.

Answer (score 3):

Remove column constraint: `not null` to `null`

```
ALTER TABLE test ALTER COLUMN column_01 DROP NOT NULL;
```

Comment: That doesn't look like valid T-SQL. Although the question was marked with SQL, note that the question explicitly refers to SQL Server which only accepts T-SQL.

Answer (score -2):

Reference: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-can-we-remove-NOT-NULL-constraint-from-a-column-of-an-existing-MySQL-table

```
ALTER TABLE tableName MODIFY columnName columnType NULL;
```